# What is the term for a word that alters the degree or severity of the subsequent word?

Tags: modifiers

What is the term for a word that alters the degree or severity of the subsequent word?  In the example below, what is the term for "somewhat"?

Ex: He was somewhat unhappy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article [Intensifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier) refers to them as *degree modifiers*, or more specifically *degree adverbs* (or *adverbs of degree*).

Answer (score 1):

It's known simply as an adverb.

An adverb modifies or describes in some way a verb, an adjective, or another adverb.  The following sentences have italicized adverbs, used in various ways:

> He was *inconsolably* unhappy.
>
> She ran *quickly* in the 100-yard dash.
>
> I found his ignorance of the subject *quite* astounding!
>
> *Completely* and *blindly* oblivious to the *faux pas* [not an adverb] he had just committed, he made us all feel *very* uncomfortable being there.
>
> *Teal* green emeralds are *simply* and *absolutely* my favorite gemstones.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional grammar, such words are *modifiers*. If the word or phrase modified is a nominal, the modifier is an *adjective*:

> John had a *severe* headache.

Otherwise the modifier is an *adverb*:

> John had an *intolerably* severe headache.  (*modifying an adjective*)
>   John had a *quite* intolerably severe headache. (*modifying another adverb*)

Adverbs of this sort (“adverbs of degree”) may also modify verbs, but the language is usually not very happy with placing them before the verb:

> <sup>?</sup> John severely suffered from headaches.
>     John suffered severely from headaches.